# SQL insert statement syntax error

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to insert this name on the uname database field. But it seems its not doing good. Anhy help will be appreciated. I already check by the way all the sources of help that I could have. However its still the same.

```
Public Conn_OLE As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Public myCMD As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Public myDR As OleDb.OleDbDataReader

Public Sub ConOpenDB_OLE() 'Use to connect to a database via oledb
    Try
        Conn_OLE = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Conn_OLE.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =C:\Users\DHALIA\Downloads\ThesisSystem - Copy\ThesisSystem - Copy\Thesis_Try_1\ThesisDB.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=mdr_mvp"
        Conn_OLE.Open()
        Conn_OLE.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    ConOpenDB_OLE()
    Conn_OLE.Open()
    myCMD.CommandText = "INSERT INTO USER ([uname],) VALUES (@uname)"

    myCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", UsernameTextBox.Text)

    myCMD.Connection = Conn_OLE
    myCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myCMD.Dispose()
    Conn_OLE.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you have an extra comma after `[uname]` in here: `"INSERT INTO USER ([uname],) VALUES (@uname)"`?

Comment: `([uname],)` -> delete the comma + User is a keyword so: `INSERT INTO [USER] ([uname]) VALUES (@uname)` should do it

Comment: USER is a reserved keyword in access, you need square brackets around it and remove the colon after uname

Comment: [Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html)

Comment: Dont try to use a global DbCommand object or DbReader - they are query-specific and not reusable.  Trying to do so will result in other problems

Comment: Oh sweet potato! that one got me! I didn't realized that. Now it perfectly works! thanks Mark, Alex B. and to you Steve! Really appreciated. I've been on the front of my laptop for several hours. Haha so noobz of me. thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USER is a reserved keyword in Access, you need square brackets around it and fix the typo after the *uname* field: (no comma is required after the last field listed)

```
CMD.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [USER] ([uname]) VALUES (@uname)"
```

Also, I suggest you to change your code that creates the connection, to

```
Public Function ConOpenDB_OLE() As OleDbConnection
    Dim con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =C:\Users\DHALIA\Downloads\ThesisSystem - Copy\ThesisSystem - Copy\Thesis_Try_1\ThesisDB.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=mdr_mvp"
    con.Open()
    Return con

End Sub
```

This allows you to write this code

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    Using con = ConOpenDB_OLE()
        myCMD.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [USER] ([uname]) VALUES (@uname)"
        myCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", UsernameTextBox.Text)
        myCMD.Connection = con
        myCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

In this way, you don't need anymore a global variable to keep your connection, you just get it when you need it and with the using statement you don't risk to forget the proper closing and disposing also in case of exceptions.

Comment: You might want to follow your own advice and put brackets around that User table.  :-)

Comment: ...and remove the comma

Comment: If I could get 10 cents for every error caused by a copy/paste I would be millionaire now.